# Ps2 survival game I need the name!

Tags: story-identification, video-games

Im trying to remember the name of this ps2 game I used to play as a kid it was a 2 player game and it had a fat white character and a skinny black character and we worked together killing skeletons in some type of graveyard we had guns and when we ran out of ammo I think we had melee weapons and had to run around the graveyard area and they would emerge from under ground google is no help at all hoping someone here can be thanks in advance it was also more of a survival game

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  We don't know when you were a kid, so what year would this have been?

Comment: Consider breaking this paragraph up into sentences for readability.

Comment: I was around 6 maybe and to @OrganicMarble idk what you mean but I hope this helps.. The game is a survival based game. As far as I can remember for an introduction a white character and a black character one had a machine gun and other maybe a shot gun, first map or scene we played in was a cemetery/graveyard and these were humans not gauntlet dark legacy which I have also played growing up.. but this was 2 humans trying to find a path out of cemetery I would assume and skeletons would emerge from the ground and attack hope this was a bit more detailed and helpful it’s about all I can remembe

Answer (score 4):

Possibly Gauntlet: Dark Legacy? It's a co-op PS2 game, which does involve working together to kill skeletons in a graveyard. The skinny black character could be the Sorceress, and a chunkier white character might be the Knight or the Dwarf. See if the gameplay footage looks familiar (this is from the Gamecube version, but the PS2 version is similar):